# Is there a way to calculate correlation between two variables in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm aware of calculating correlations in Excel and SAS but I'm newer to SQL and was curious if there is a way to calculate the correlation of a relationship between two variables.

Comment: SQL is a language. Please tag your database.

Comment: SQL generally does not have variables. Could you give an example of what you're trying to do? And which SQL database are you using?

Comment: I agree with the comments above. For example for MySQL if you want to find correlation between column A and B you can use the `corr`  aggregator: `SELECT CORR(A,B) FROM Table`

Comment: Please define "correlation".

Comment: If your db does not have a function, here is a formula: `avg(x*y) - avg(x)*avg(y)`.